# What are the pros and cons of using dynamic array of records vs. TList<TMyRecord> in Delphi?

Tags: arrays, delphi, storage, record

This is a theoretical question intended to generate a look-up list of pros and cons of different data storage ways in Delphi.

Let's say we have a record:

```
type
  TMyRecord = record 
    X,Y,Z: Single; 
    IsValid: Boolean; 
  end;
```

Basic options of storing an array of such records are:

- `array of TMyRecord;`
- custom descendant of `TList` with getter/setter
- `TList<TMyRecord>;`

I'm specifically interested about #1 vs #3 comparison, how much is the difference between those, especially performance-wise.

Comment: #2 & #3 are essentially the same, template does customization for you. With array you'll have your records stored contiguously.

Comment: Actually not. `TList<T>` operates the values not the pointers (unlike the TList).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`TList<T>` pros:

- **Array doesn't have useful methods for adding/inserting/deleting/sorting/searching, TList does.**
- TList has Notify method that could be overriden to perform some custom actions on item addition/deletion.

`TList<T>` cons:

- **`TList<T>[i]` actually returns a *copy* of its element. So you can't write something like `TList<TMyRec>[idx].SomeField := foo`. Instead, you have to use temporary variable. Array obviously allows such expression.**
  *David Heffernan mentioned `TList<T>.List` which eliminates this drawback; however, it appeared only in XE3*
- TList is an object which should be deleted <s>at program finish</s> when not needed.
- System.Generics.Collections unit could add plenty of binary size to a project that wasn't using System.Classes unit before.

For myself I wrote `TRecordList<T>` class which operates items as pointers (like classic TList does).

Comment: `TList<T>.List` is the dyn array, so no need for copies. In perf terms, dyn array has no advantage.

Comment: Isn't your `TRecordList<T>` bad for caches?

Comment: "deleted at program finish"...actually it should be deleted/freed before going out of scope or when no longer used.

Comment: Indeed, if you wait until program finish, then there's not much point in freeing it at all 'cos the system will claim it back.

Comment: @David Heffernan: thanks for mentioning `TList<T>.List`, it was added only in XE3 while I'm still on XE2. @jpfollenius, you're surely right. @David Heffernan: maybe it's bad for caches but it's good for item inserting/sorting etc.

Comment: @Fr0sT Yes, it does depend a little on the usage scenarios. Lists of pointers can be effective in some situations. I suppose I was imagining linear access patterns

Answer (score 7):

**tl;dr**

- A list of pointers to independent blocks of memory is unfriendly to the cache and should be avoided.
- Dynamic arrays have the same performance characteristics as `TList<T>`.
- `TList<T>` offers many conveniences to the programmer that dynamic arrays do not afford.

---

The implementation of `TList<T>` is that the items are stored in a dynamic array. So there are essentially no performance differences between `TList<T>` and `TArray<T>`.

Of course, the dynamic array gives you direct access to the elements without making copies. You can do the same using the [`List`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.List) property of `TList<T>` if that matters. In fact that property means that in performance terms at least `TList<T>` is a match for a plain dynamic array.

Beyond performance, using `TList<T>` gives you all sorts of convenience over a raw dynamic array. I don't need to enumerate these conveniences. You can see them clearly from the list of public methods and properties.

Since performance is important to you, you should tackle the real performance issue with the code in the question. Namely the fact that you packed your record. That will lead to the majority of instances of the record being mis-aligned. And that has dire performance implications. If you care about performance, you will align structures.

Your middle option, a list of pointers is not really worth considering. It will likely scatter memory all over the address space and be unfriendly to the cache.

Comment: When I mention in the first line, that this is theoretical question or not my code (previous time you made implications) - I mean exactly that. The code snippet was just an example. I don't know where you read that I have performance issues %)

Comment: @Krom The question I answered, before you changed it, had a packed record. These have terrible perf due to mis-alignment. It would have been grossly remiss of me to ignore that. Not least because the two things you are comparing have identical perf because they are fundamentally just arrays. Perf cannot really be bettered for them. The only perf issue in the question I answered was the packed array. And mis-alignment is a massive issue if you have it.

Comment: You can judge for yourself whether or not you have problems with alignment. Do a search in your codebase for packed.

Comment: `packed` deserved a comment and I'm thankful to you for doing it. However my main question is about usage and performance differences between #1-#3 given **everything else is the same** (packed or not). Thanks

Comment: Fine. I already answered that too. There is no difference in perf.